# How do I generate multiple reports? I'm only getting the daily report right now

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

daily="FILE_PATH/Daily"
weekly="/FILE_PATH/Weekly"
semianually="/FILE_PATH/SemiAnnually"

_endDate=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
_day=$(date +"%u")

if [ $_day -ge 1  ] || [ $_day -le 7 ]
then
    backNumDays="180"
    directory=$semianually
    _beginDate=$(date -d "183 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
    report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"SemiAnnualReport".csv"
else
    :
fi

if [ $_day -ge 1  ] || [ $_day -le 7 ]
then
    backNumDays="7"
    directory=$weekly
    _beginDate=$(date -d "7 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
    report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"WeeklyReport".csv"
else
    :
fi

if [ $_day -ge 1  ] || [ $_day -le 7 ]
then
    backNumDays="1"
    directory=$daily
    _beginDate=$(date -d "1 day ago" +"%m%d%Y")
    report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"DailyReport".csv"
fi


#_____sql query_______
exec_file_Report()
    {

    status=`/SIDS/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client/bin/sqlplus -S << +++
    $DB_CONNECT
    --
    SET head on
    SET feedback OFF
    SET pagesize 10000
    SET linesize 2000;
    SET colsep ,
    set trimspool on
    set trimout on
    set trims on
    set UNDERLINE OFF
    set verify off
    set echo off
    set term off

    spool "$directory/$report"

    SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rownum <= $backNumDays
        ;
    spool off
    exit
+++
`
}

exec_file_Report
```

I can not figure out why a daily report is being generated. The cron is setup to run: Everyday for daily, Sunday for weekly and last day of month for semiannual. The reason all my ifs are using the same parameters it simply to test my code in the event multiple conditions occur such as Sunday also being the last day of the month.

Comment: Can you try to explain this a little more clearly? Like, what do you want to happen? Why are you testing `if [ $_day -ge 1 ] || [ $_day -le 7 ]`? Isn’t that *always* true? Are you just running this script 429 (365+52+12) times per year? Is this your “real” code, or just a dummy test version? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: This is currently a test version because I want them all to be true thus, generate all 3 reports. This is to see if days like March 31st which is the last day of month and a Sunday, will generate a report for both Weekly (Sunday) and semiannual (last day of month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I’m missing something,
but I guess you want (this test version of) your script
to generate all three reports every time you run it. 
But the script just isn’t set up
to generate multiple reports in a single invocation. 
The general flow of what happens when you run the script is

```
if (condition that’s always true)
then
    backNumDays="180"
    directory="$semiannually"
        ︙
else
    :
fi

if (condition that’s always true)
then
    backNumDays="7"
    directory="$weekly"
        ︙
else
    :
fi

if (condition that’s always true)
then
    backNumDays="1"
    directory="$daily"
        ︙
fi


(Generate daily report)
```

You need to do something like

```
(define exec_file_Report function)

if (it’s the last day of the month)
then
    backNumDays="180"
    directory="$semiannually"
        ︙
    exec_file_Report
fi

if (it’s Sunday)
then
    backNumDays="7"
    directory="$weekly"
        ︙
    exec_file_Report
fi

backNumDays="1"
directory="$daily"
    ︙
exec_file_Report
```

This script *can* generate all three reports in a single invocation. 
For example, on February 10, February 17, February 24,
March 3, March 10, March 17 and March 24 (all of which are Sundays),
it will do the monthly report and the daily report. 
On February 28 it will do the semiannual report and the daily report. 
On Sunday March 31 it will do all three. 
So you only need to run the script every day;
you don’t need the three cron lines.

Now you’re saying that, on any of the above multiple-report days,
you want the daily report to be generated at 2 PM
and the other(s) at 11:59 PM. 
This is the sort of detail
that should have been included in the question
when I asked for clarification. 
To handle this, you must make the script either smarter or less smart. 
I recommend making it less smart. 
Change it, not to *figure out* for itself what report(s) to generate,
but to take an argument telling it which report to generate. 
Something like this:

```
(define exec_file_Report function)

case "$1" in
     (semiannual)
        backNumDays="180"
        directory="$semiannually"
            ︙
        exec_file_Report
        ;;

     (weekly)
        backNumDays="7"
        directory="$weekly"
            ︙
        exec_file_Report
        ;;

    (daily)
        backNumDays="1"
        directory="$daily"
            ︙
        exec_file_Report
        ;;
esac
```

And then keep the crontab entries you have now, but add the arguments:

```
0       14      *       *       *       /path/to/your/script daily
59      23      *       *       0       /path/to/your/script weekly
59      23     (last)   *       *       /path/to/your/script semiannual
```

Ummm — how are you using cron to run a job on the last day of the month?

Warning: I have not tested the above.

Notes:

- There’s no reason to do `else   :`.
- There’s no reason to use an `if` to test a condition that’s always true
  to handle code that you want to execute every time.
- `exec` is the name of a Unix system function and a shell command. 
  Using it as part of the name of a function is confusing.

Comment: My plan is to set up 3 cron jobs because these will be required to run at certain times. Here is how I have it setup currently:
Daily - everyday at 2PM 
Weekly - every Sunday at 11:59PM
SemiAnnually - every last day of the month at 11:59PM

Sorry I'm really new to scripting and I really appreciate your insight. I figured since it will run on 3 different occasions, it will go through the if statements to determine what file needs to be generated. My concern are the days like March 31st which will be a Sunday and the last day of the month.

Comment: For the last days of the month I'm just doing something like:

55   23   31   1,3,5,7,8,10,12   *

Comment: Sorry I'm just a little confused. So I'm defining the exec_file_Report function before the cases and calling then calling the function in each of the cases but not getting a report at all now. I tried doing it this way but using my if conditions but I get an TNS error when manually running.

Comment: Hey I just want to say thank you! I used cases previously but just tried passing the "day" as an argument. I'm really new to all this and your post really helped guide me to the answer. I will post an update on how I achieved this with your insight when I get back home. Again, thank you!!